# Avoid autoscroll to Disqus comment section of page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, disqus

I'm building a Wordpress website and I have run into a problem where the page autoscrolls to the Disqus comment section as it's loading the comments. This is really annoying and I am trying to figure out a way to keep the focus at the top of the page even though the Disqus comments are loading below, or have the Disqus comments load only once you scroll down to them.

I tried using this jQuery script but it didn't work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(this).scrollTop(0);
});
```

I also tried using some other Javascript scripts but they didn't work either. Is there a simple way to do this?